# opening netlink socket will use same pid then bind and creation fails

Tags: c++, c, linux, sockets, ipc

I have an application that tries to open a netlink socket and we somehow get the same pid “port” as a previous netlink socket (there are many forks), so the netlink socket bind fails, and the creation fails.
Does anyone know what is happening in this scenario, or any one has any advice ? 
how can I avoid it ?

Comment: Code to demonstrate this scenario would be great. According to [man 7 netlink](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/netlink.7.html) the nl_pid should not matter much to the application. Try reading the section Address formats, if you have not already.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have multiple server that can hear to the same port.

Solution will be to change the port of the new server (fork son) or close the dad server before opening the new one.

May i ask why do you want to open multiple server?